# Two queues and different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have 2 queues A and B. Main thread is responsible for filling the queues. There is a threadpool of 3 threads responsible for reading from queues. Both Queues are ArrayBlockingQueue. 
Lets say main thread is filling the queues in this way (A1,B1),(A2,B2),(A3,B3),(A4,B4) and so on. A1 and B1 collectively makes a whole data.
Is it possible for a any thread to read data like (A3,B4) at any point. If yes then how can i avoid it. I want every thread to read data the altogether.
e.g thread1 should read both (A1,B1) and thread2 (A2,B2) and so on.

Comment: Why don't you put the data into another object and have only one queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As so often, the answer is: *depends*.

Of course you can implement something that would follow the outlined approach and that in the end is "correct". But: getting there will be **hard**.

A much more straight forward way: fix your broken design. If the two entries within the two queues are **only** meaningful together - then create a class that wraps around one A and one B - and put such objects into a **single** queue.